# sections of vector bundles transversal to a divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-curves, divisors

Let $X$ a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$, $S$ a finite subscheme of $X$.

$E$ a vector bundle over $X$ with a divisor $D$. 
We look at the sections $A:=H^{0}(X,E)$ with $\deg E$ big enough.

Is it true, that the set $A^{0}_{S}$ consisting of sections that meet transversally $D$ and avoid $D$ at the points of $S$ is an open subset? And what should be the bound for $\deg E$ so that it holds?

Comment: A section of $E$ cannot meet a point in $D$ transversally unless it avoids it. Is this what you have in mind ?

Comment: I mean that for a point $x\in X$ and $s$ a section of $E$, either $x\in S$ and the $s(x)\notin D$, either $x\in X-S$ and then s(x) needs to meet transversally $D$.